# Se muestran atributos pero no el contenido

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

estoy haciendo una consulta en sql
Donde me piden obtener el id del producto, litros por unidad, familia, existencia y venta
Me muestra los atributos qué estoy llamando pero no me muestra contenido...
Alguien podría ayudarme y ver que es lo que esta saliendo mal?

```sql
SELECT
  bdproductos.id_producto,
  Lts_x_Uni,
  Familia,
  Existencia2,
  VENTA_NETA_PESOS
FROM bdproductos
INNER JOIN inventario
  ON bdproductos.id_invent = inventario.id_invent
INNER JOIN rentabilidad
  ON inventario.id_invent = rentabilidad.id_invent
WHERE bdproductos.id_producto IN (SELECT
  bdproductos.id_producto
FROM bdproductos)
```

Comment: Si no te muestra nada es porque no hay nada que mostrar básicamente. Revisa tus inner join, puede que no exista coincidencias.

Comment: La condición en la cláusula `WHERE` se ve sospechosa... Le estás diciendo que traiga todos los `id_producto` de la misma tabla que tienes en la cláusula `FROM`. Intenta sin el `WHERE`, de seguir sin resultados, prueba con lo que sugiere @isanchezo. Puedes depurar ejecutando la consulta por partes, primero hasta el `FROM`, luego le agregas uno de los `INNER JOIN`, luego el siguiente y luego el `WHERE` hasta que encuentres el problema.